# Array concatenation in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization, concatenation, array-initialization

1. How do I smartly initialize an Array with two (or more) other arrays in C#?

   ```
   double[] d1 = new double[5];
   double[] d2 = new double[3];
   double[] dTotal = new double[8]; // I need this to be {d1 then d2}
   ```
2. Another question: How do I concatenate C# arrays efficiently?

Comment: If you have arrays that you need to change or mix and match like this, you should probably be use a generic List instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate two arrays in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547252/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw.aspx):

```
double[] d1 = new double[5];
double[] d2 = new double[3];
double[] dTotal = new double[d1.Length + d2.Length];

d1.CopyTo(dTotal, 0);
d2.CopyTo(dTotal, d1.Length);
```

Comment: Msdn is a little bit unclear, but the index parameter specifies the index in the destination array.

Comment: You need d1.length - 1, I believe

Comment: You're right; I misunderstood.   Sorry.  @Rubys: No, you don't.

Comment: First I copy 5 doubles from d1 to dTotal. Then I copy d2 to dTotal starting in index 5. If I use `d1.Lenght - 1` I'll start at index 4 and I'll lost the last value of d1.

Answer (score 6):

```
var dTotal = d1.Concat(d2).ToArray();
```

You could probably make it 'better' by creating dTotal first, and then just copying both inputs with `Array.Copy`.

Comment: This will be inefficient for large arrays.

Comment: @SLaks: That's why I added the little extra bit, but even for meduim size arrays (up to 10000 elements), you would probably not even notice the difference. Also Enumerable may provide a fast option for `Concat` if both are arrays (will have to look at source to confirm). Update: It does NOT have a fast option for anything.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx), like this:

```
double[] d1 = new double[5];
double[] d2 = new double[3];
double[] dTotal = new double[d1.length + d2.length];

Array.Copy(d1, 0, dTotal, 0, d1.Length);
Array.Copy(d2, 0, dTotal, d1.Length, d2.Length);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Linq;

int[] array1 = { 1, 3, 5 };
int[] array2 = { 0, 2, 4 };

// Concat array1 and array2.
var result1 = array1.Concat(array2).ToArray();
```