# Different action on parameter that could be array

Tags: c#

Here T could be an array or a single object.  How can add the array to an arraylist or add a single object to the same arraylist.  This gives me a build-time error that the overloaded match for `AddRange` has invalid arguments.

```
T loadedContent;
if (typeof(T).IsArray)
{
    contentArrayList.AddRange(loadedContent);
}
else
{
    contentArrayList.Add(loadedContent);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2788636/210709

Comment: what is the type of contentArrayList?

Comment: I removed the XNA tag because your question is really about C#. But on the XNA front, it is generally very unusual to need to make a "list" of content that you have loaded. Just let `ContentManager` deal with it.

Comment: (And on the C# front: this is a fairly flagrant non-use of the typing system. I could give you an answer of how you could do this... but you probably shouldn't be doing this in the first place.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Corrected my answer after checking some of the rules around casting to type `Array`.

All specific types of arrays, such as `int[]`, `string[]`, or `MyCustomObject[]` derive from the base `Array` class, and as such, they implement the `ICollection` interface, which is what the `ArrayList.AddRange` method accepts as a parameter.

Assuming that your `contentArrayList` variable is an `ArrayList` object, you should be able to cast your `loadedContent` variable to `ICollection`:

```
contentArrayList.AddRange((ICollection)loadedContent)
```

<s>Alternatively, you could combine the check for whether it is an array with the cast:</s>

```
Array loadedContentAsArray = loadedContent as Array;
if (loadedContentAsArray != null)
{
    contentArrayList.AddRange(loadedContentAsArray);
}
```

Comment: Indeed you could use a [Type Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on the `T` parameter to ensure it implements `ICollection`
Example: `where T : ICollection`

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Dr. Wily's Apprentice will work but I would like to make some side comments.

You must have design issue in your code if you use generics but you are still committed to a specific data type. Basically you destroy the purpose of the generics, as stated on MSDN:

> Generics allow you to define type-safe data structures, without committing to actual data types.

Maybe you should reconsider some refactoring, maybe by adding methods with different parameters or something...

Comment: I'm not commited to a specific type, but rather either an array of objects or a single object.  This is because LoadContent returns either of these depending on the parameter (single or [])

Answer (score 0):

If your contentList is of Type ArrayList, I would go that way.

```
        ICollection contentArray = loadedContent as ICollection;
        if (contentArray != null)
            contentList.AddRange(contentArray);
        else
            contentList.Add(loadedContent);
```