# Merge two string arrays in .NET/C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, c#-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Merging two arrays in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/merging-two-arrays-in-net) 
>   [How do I concatenate two arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547252/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c)

How could I merge two `string[]` variables?

Example:

```
string[] x = new string[] { "apple", "soup", "wizard" };
string[] y = new string[] { Q.displayName, Q.ID.toString(), "no more cheese" };
```

I want to add these two so the content of `x` is:`{"apple", "soup", "wizard",Q.displayName, Q.ID.toString(), "no more cheese"};` in that order. Is this possible? If the result has to go into a new string array that's fine; I just would like to know how to make it happen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788636/array-concatenation-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547276/120955):

```
var z = new string[x.length + y.length];
x.CopyTo(z, 0);
y.CopyTo(z, x.length);
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

```
string[] a = new string[] { "A"};
string[] b = new string[] { "B"};

string[] concat = new string[a.Length + b.Length];

a.CopyTo(concat, 0);
b.CopyTo(concat, a.Length);
```

Then `concat` is your concatenated array.

Comment: sorry dude it's 2.0 no such thing as .concat

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned .NET 2.0 and LINQ isn't available, you're really stuck doing in "manually":

```
string[] newArray = new string[x.Length + y.Length];
for(int i = 0; i<x.Length; i++)
{
   newArray[i] = x[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i<y.Length; i++)
{
   newArray[i + x.Length] = y[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
     string[] front = { "foo", "test","hello" , "world" };
     string[] back = { "apple", "soup", "wizard", "etc" };


     string[] combined = new string[front.Length + back.Length];
     Array.Copy(front, combined, front.Length);
     Array.Copy(back, 0, combined, front.Length, back.Length);
```