# How to append some object arrays in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I concatenate two arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547252/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c)

How do I append some object arrays into one big object array?

For example, I have 3 elements of type: `object[]` and want to make one of it. How to do this?

Comment: Do you have to use an array? If not I would highly recommend a List (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: You want to merge arrays right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this:

```
object[] element1 = ...;
object[] element2 = ...;
object[] element3 = ...;
var list = new List<object>();
list.AddRange(element1);
list.AddRange(element2);
list.AddRange(element3);
var result = list.ToArray();
```

An alternative would be:

```
var result = element1.Concat(element2).Concat(element3).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call the method [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) on them

```
 var newArray = a.Concat(b).Concat(c).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you need to use the combined list, the most performant solution would be to feed your arrays into an iterator block and return at enumerable :

```
IEnumerable<object> CombineArrays ( params object[] arrays )
{
     foreach (object[] arr in arrays )
     {
          foreach (object obj in arr)
          { 
               yield return obj;
          }
     }
} 

... 

IEnumerable<object> result = CombineArrays ( array1, array2, array3);
```

This way will not need any additional storage to for the new combined list. The  [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) result will just enumerate over the arrays in turn. You can process the result using any of the Linq operators - so you can group, filter and select as much as you want.

If you need to create a writable list from this you will need to call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on the result.

Answer (score 1):

Or the good, old fashioned way:

```
object[] objects = new object[objects1.Length + objects2.Length + objects3.Length];
int i = 0;
for(int j = 0; j<objects1.Length; j++)
  objects[i++] = objects1[j];
for(int j = 0; j<objects2.Length; j++)
  objects[i++] = objects2[j];
for(int j = 0; j<objects3.Length; j++)
  objects[i++] = objects3[j];
```

Comment: No need to complicate things like that..

Comment: I wouldn't call it "complicated". It's probably what the compiler will end up creating.

Comment: +1: This code is working, no need to downvote.

Comment: Sorry but when I ask "How I reach Mapple street"? I prefer straight answer giving me the shortest path, not answer that send me walking in circles. True, the final result is the same but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: This should be the answer if the question was about C/C++. I'm sorry but this is not acceptable for C# programming.