# What's the best way to add an item to a C# array?

Tags: c#, arrays, extension-methods

I have the following array:

```
int[] numbers;
```

Is there a good way to add a number to the array? I didn't find an extension method that concats 2 arrays, I wanted to do something like:

```
numbers = numbers.Concat(new[] { valueToAdd });
```

Comment: You concatenation is almost correct , it just needs a `.ToArray()` at the end. But if you're going to do it many times, it is better to use a `List<int>` or other appropriate collection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To concatenate 2 ararys look at: [How do I concatenate two arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547252/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c)

The best solution I can suggest is to simply use

```
List<int> numbers
```

And when needed call the ToArray() extension method (and not the opposite).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

```
var z = new int[x.length + y.length];
x.CopyTo(z, 0);
y.CopyTo(z, x.length);
```

or

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.AddRange(x);
list.AddRange(y);
int[] z = list.ToArray();
```

or

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 3, 5 };
int[] array2 = { 0, 2, 4 };

// Concat array1 and array2.
var result1 = array1.Concat(array2);
```

Comment: You need to add `ToArray()` at the last statement to improve OP's code since he wants an array as result.

Comment: i just gave him option...he can go for list...that is the best and easy way...  :)