# how can I take 3 string arrays(contains files) into a single array

Tags: c#

```
string[] filesHD = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, filepattern1);

string[] filesDT = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, filepattern2);

string[] filesTD = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, filepattern3);
```

My `filesHD[]` array contains 2 files. `filesDT[]` contains 2 files and `filesTD[]` also contains 2 files.

I want to create a single string Array which will contain all the 6 files of `filesHD`, `filesDT`, `filesTD`.

```
string[] Allfiles = new string [filesHD + filesDT + filesTD]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547252/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 5):

There are several methods to do this, in C# the easiest is probably:

```
var allFiles = filesHD.Union(filesDT).Union(filesTD);
```

OR

```
var allFiles = filesHD.Concat(filesDT).Concat(filesTD);
```

You can end it with a call to `.ToArray()` if you will be enumerating it more than once, if you are just going to `foreach` over it once, don't worry about the `.ToArray()`.  The difference between `Union` and `Concat` is `Union` uses the default equality comparer to ignore duplicates.

Comment: `Concat` is better as `Union` will strip out duplicates, we don't want that.

Comment: @unlimit yeah, I noted that at the end of my answer.  However, it may be something the user wants.

Comment: @unlimit but if we're talking about files from the same folder, we might want to strip out duplicates...

Comment: @nurchi from the question it does not look like OP wants that. However, this answers explains both the options.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try following code?

```
List<string> AllFiles = new List<string>();
AllFiles.Concat(filesHD);
AllFiles.Concat(filesDT);
AllFiles.Concat(filesTD);

var strAllFiles = AllFiles.ToArray();
```

Add reference: `Using System.Linq;`

Note: Typed without compiler, couldn't check for syntax errors.

Comment: FYI to your note: The `ToList` on each array isn't necessary. `Concat` takes `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be simple, you could also try the following:

```
List<string> lstAllFiles=new List<string>();
lstAllFiles.AddRange(filesHD);
lstAllFiles.AddRange(filesDT);
lstAllFiles.AddRange(filesTD);
string[] strAllFiles=lstAllFiles.ToArray();
```

This method does not use Linq...
Hope this helps.