# Merging two string lists if check box is checked

Tags: c#, list, if-statement

I have string list

```
string [] lines = {"1","2","3"};
```

Then I have another string list

```
string [] linesTwo = {"2.1","2.2","2.3"};
```

How can I make a combination of those lists when checkBox1 is checked? If checkBox1 is checked I would like to have list like:

```
{"1","2","2.1","2.2","2.3","3"}
```

EDIT:
My lists do not actually contain any numbers so any sorting is not possible.

Comment: Can you check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547252/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written code for your problem. I am just sorting the array by using Sort attribute for giving your exact output.

```
string [] lines = {"1","2","3"};
    string [] linesTwo = {"2.1","2.2","2.3"};
    var CombinedString = new string[lines.Length + linesTwo.Length];

    Array.Sort<string>(CombinedString );



    if(CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
           lines.CopyTo(CombinedString , 0);
            linesTwo.CopyTo(CombinedString , lines.Length);
            Array.Sort<string>(CombinedString );
        }
```

[Fiddle Code here..Check this way](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R5UU1k)

Comment: Is there any other way than sorting? If lists don't contain any numbers and I still want to linesTwo to start at 3rd row and also have that "3" at the end. I could to separate string "lines" to two different pieces but I don't feel that it is right.

Comment: If i understand your requirement correctly, DO you need to add linesTwo string add inside the first string array after 2 elements... ? Can you please ellaborate your question..:)

Comment: Yes. First I tried like this if it helps to understand.
lines={"1","2",linesTwo,"3"}

Answer (score 0):

Concat the two and sort the items.

```
var newline = lines.Concat(linesTwo).OrderBy(i => i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this to merge two lists of the same type:

```
list = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on how you view is set up. Assuming you are using WPF, you could use a [CompositeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<CompositeCollection>
     <ColectionContainer Source="{Binding listOne}" />
     <ColectionContainer Source="{Binding listOne}" />
</CompositeContainer>
```

If you are not using WPF, it is likely you will have to manually control this by subscribing to an event on the Checkbox:

```
public void Checkbox1_Checked(...) {
    combinedList = lines.Concat(linesTwo);
    ...
}
```

If you can provide a little more information on what you're trying to do, we might be able to help a little more: What code creates your checkbox? how are these lists going to be used?

Answer (score 0):

If you asking how to do that on webforms than: 
1) Set your textBox to **autoPostBack** 
2) generate **event** *CheckedChanged* 
3) Code below is code in that event

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//checkbox name CheckBox_1
{
            string[] merged;
            string[] lines = { "1", "2", "3" };
            string[] linesTwo = { "2.1", "2.2", "2.3" };
            if(CheckBox1.Checked) // check is checkbox checked
            {
                merged = lines.Concat(linesTwo).ToArray(); // merge
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

using **Linq** `Concat` you can concat the two arrays. Then you need to sort them using `OrderBy`,

```
var newline = lines.Concat(linesTwo).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
```