# How to Split item of array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

I have a problem with my array.
My array name is `word[3]` have 3 items.

```
word[0] = "Listen Repeat"
word[1] = "Tune"
word[2] = "Landing Page"
```

I want `words[0]` split new two item and add to exist item in array.

```
words = Regex.Split(words[0], @"\s{1,}").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

So, my array becomes like:

```
word[0] = "Listen"
word[1] = "Repeat"
```

But I want my array like:

```
word[0] = "Listen"
word[1] = "Repeat"
word[2] = "Tune"
word[3] = "Landing Page"
```

Note:
If using add two arrays, this arrays not sort.
You can see my next item in array like:

`word[0] = "Listen"`

to 
`word[1] = "Repeat"`

to
`word[2] = "Tune"`

to 
`word[3] = "Langding Page"`

If I using `AddRange` this will like:

from
`word[0] = "Listen"`

to
`word[1] = "Tune"`

to 
`word[2] = "Langding Page"`

to 
`word[3] = "Repeat"`

This code will delete exist item and create new arrays with two items.
I don't know how to add exist array.

I tried with `Append` but it not success.

Comment: Very unclear what you've tried - array does not have `Append`... There are many questions discussion adding/replacing items in array / merging arrays in all possible ways. Make sure to provide results of your research as links with sample code that did not work (see [MCVE] for guidance on code samples).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. Almost in Stackoverflow. You add two arrays. At here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547252/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c
But your array not sorted. You can see my next item in array like `word[0] = "Listen"` to `word[1] = "Repeat"`. If I using `AddRange` this will like: `word[0] = "Listen"` to `word[1] = "Tune"` to `word[2] = "Langding Page"` to `word[3] = "Repeat"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via linq and use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var word = new string[3];
word[0] = "Listen Repeat";
word[1] = "Tune";
word[2] = "Landing Page";

word = word.SelectMany(x => Regex.Split(x, @"\s{1,}").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))).ToArray();
```

If you just want to split a specific item then you can use this function.

```
public static string[] SplitItem(string[] input, int index)
{
    var l = new List<string>(input.Length);
    l.AddRange(input.Take(index));
    l.AddRange(Regex.Split(input[index], @"\s{1,}").Where(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y)));
    l.AddRange(input.Skip(index + 1).TakeWhile(x => true));
    return l.ToArray();
}


var word = new string[3];
word[0] = "Listen Repeat";
word[1] = "Tune";
word[2] = "Landing Page";

word = SplitItem(word,0);
```

Comment: But I want my array like: "Listen" "Repeat" "Tune" "Landing Page"

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly I tested. It working in my case. I not using `word.Dump();`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114989/discussion-between-vn-lc-and-dmitry-dovgopoly).