# Copy string array to an existing string array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

```
 String[] search1 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(voiceSource, callId + " "+ separator +"*."+ fileFormat +"")
                         .Where(file => Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith( callId + " "+ separator +""))
                         .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                         .ToArray();
```

Now I would like to copy the following array to the above search1. On the other word, I would like to combine two array.

```
  String[] search2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(voiceSource, callId + ""+ separator +"*."+ fileFormat +"")
                         .Where(file => Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith(callId + ""+ separator +""))
                         .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                         .ToArray();
```

Please note that search1 may be of zero length. Any help?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve - can you clarify?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304816/most-efficient-way-to-append-arrays-in-c

Comment: Do you mean you want to just concatenate two arrays? If so, use LINQ: `a.Concat(b).ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

```
search3 = new type[search1.Length + search2.Length];
search1.CopyTo(search3, 0);
search2.CopyTo(search3, search1.Length);
```

where type is the type of element in array

from [How do I concatenate two arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547252/how-do-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-c)

Comment: Instead of copying the code from another answer, flag as duplicate of the other question.